# Build not work after go module changes in 1.16

Tags: go

Updated go 1.15.7 -> 1.16

Project tree:

```
src/customA
src/customB
src/customC
src/mainA
src/mainB
```

To build I used:

```
export GOPATH=`pwd`
go build mainA
go build mainB
```

Example how I import local packages:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "path"
    "strings"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
    . "customA"
    . "customB"
)

func main() {
...
```

Now I get:

```
package customA is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/customA)
```

How to import local package?
Can not find example. I tried

```
go mod init <customA>.
```

Is it mandatory from now on for all non standard packages to import from https://domain/ ?

Comment: See [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code) for an introduction to organizing Go code.   Import statements do not use "http" or "https", so no, it's not necessary to use https://.

Comment: If these packages make one module put them in one module if not: Make several modules and use the `replace` directive to use the local copy. All is explained in detail in https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started which you should stick to. Note that dot-imports where a bad idea even in Go 1.15

Comment: I did follow the documentation. Now I will try to get rid of import with "."

Comment: I get rid of import with ".". Did not help at all. Build & import modules documentation only contains example with https import.

Comment: go modules are mandatory from now on (1.16). I know is a huge feature. Don't like  replace directive workaround and the fact that is mandatory.

Comment: Upgrading to modules presents no real changes for most code that was structured correctly according to the documentation in the first place. If your code would require replace directives in all cases, perhaps these packages should be in the same module. If different modules are sharing the code, then you need to publish them _somewhere_, and they need to be discoverable as modules. If they only exist on your personal machine, then there is only one place to ever add the replace directive for your exceptional situation.

Comment: There is a huge bunch of go projects on https://github.com/ that will not build anymore. For simple stuff nobody wants to setup modules unless you are the company developing 99 different micro-services and 15 different teams of developers working on that.

Comment: In most cases setting up modules takes 1 trivial commit, and even the smallest independent projects seem to have no trouble adding `go.mod` and `go.sum` to their repo. If the code does not easily convert to module, it is usually an indication that it was broken in the first place, and this presents an opportunity to make the code build correctly and reliably.

Comment: if you try to add local package with replace, GOPROXY and GOSUMDB will try to verify it and fail because it dose not know about it. go.sum is generated when you download package from https-exapmle. There is option to use private GOPROXY. If you download the package then you can use replace and it will works, but verify will not check the replaced copy, I guess it only checks the original one from https:-example

Comment: What if you want split code in packages as logical units with no purpose to reuse it. I see the trend , that packages will be larger. To make a module you have to have something relay sold, otherwise you just dump it to the main package. main package will have lots of files. Simplicity officially ruined for go import! And if your company not allow you to do open source , setup the private env. will be a big  headache.

Answer (score 3):

**Local package can be added like this:**

go.mod content for main package

```
module hello

go 1.16
```

File tree:

```
go.mod
main.go
custom/custom.go
```

main.go content:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "hello/custom"
)

func main() {
...
```

Comment: that's really killer